# Degree of generating polynomial associated with two partitions

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, representation-theory, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)$ and $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_r)$ be two strictly increasing sequences of non-negative integers ($r$ and $k$ 
 may be $0$, in which case the sequence is empty, and the polynomial $f$ below is constant $1$). Define
$$f(t)=\prod_{\substack{i=1,\ldots,k\\k=1,\ldots,r}}(t^{\lambda_i}+t^{\mu_j}).$$
Is there any canonical way to describe the degree of $f$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $\mu$?

Several cases are obvious, e.g. if the length of either $\lambda$ or $\mu$ is $\le 1$ then the degree is just the sum of the longer sequence. Just from this, it seems like it might be helpful to try and find a solution by considering $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as partitions, and trying to locate some formula using their duals.. but this is completely from intuition, I really have nothing to back this on..

Anyhow, I was wondering if perhaps someone here is familiar with this function and can help me with understanding it or with finding a relevant reference.

Thanks!

---

This polynomial $f$ appears in Lusztig's dimension formula for the degree of characters of finite classical groups of Lie-type (and that's also how I came about to consider it), so I'm adding the representation theory and finite group tags, just in case someone familiar might be acquainted with this.

---

**Added**: Perhaps it would be helpful to say something extra. My *real* interest is in the function
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\lambda_i+\sum_{j=1}^r j\mu_j+\deg(f).$$
Some theoretical ideas+checking cases with $r$ and $k$ small suggest that this last sum is dependent only in the values in the sequence $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k,\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_r)$, and not on the way in which they are divided into $\lambda$ and $\mu$. I was wondering if this is known, or can be shown somehow that I can't quite see.

Comment: You mean, apart from $\deg f=\sum_{i,j}\max\{\lambda_i,\mu_j\} $?

Comment: Yes, of course that's true as well. I was wondering if there's anything more transparent..

Comment: To your "Added": Your "real interest" function is $\sum\limits_{1 \leq p \leq q \leq k+r} \max\left\{\nu_p, \nu_q\right\}$, where $\left(\nu_1,\nu_2,\ldots,\nu_{k+r}\right) = \left(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k,\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_r\right)$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, oh, awesome! so it is independent of the division into two partitions!

Comment: @darijgrinberg, it looks to me like that is the answer and should be in an answer so it can be accepted.